# "cannot find symbol" on a wsdl Java Client

Tags: java, wsdl

This is part of a lab exercise for a course I'm doing, it's not assessable, just a learning exercise.  Not sure why but the tut didn't go through it, so I just went through it at home but I'm stuck on the last part.

I'm trying to write a java WSDL client to access http://www.nanonull.com/TimeService/TimeService.asmx?WSDL - I should input UTC+10 to display the current time.  Below is the code that I have written:

```
package time;
class Client {
 public static void main(String args[]){
        TimeService service = new TimeService();
        TimeServiceSoap port= service.getTimeServiceSoap();
        String result = port.GetTimeZoneTime("UTC+10");
        System.out.println("Time is "+result);
 }

}
```

When I try and compile the code I get the following error:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_22\bin>javac -d . "c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0
_22\bin\time\Client.java"
c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_22\bin\time\Client.java:13: cannot find symbol
symbol  : method GetTimeZoneTimeResponse(java.lang.String)
location: interface time.TimeServiceSoap
        String result = port.GetTimeZoneTime("UTC+10");
                            ^
1 error
```

Any thoughts on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you mean

```
String result = port.getTimeZoneTime("UTC+10");
```

with a lowercase `g`? Java method names are case-sensitive, so it won't recognize the method if you get its letter casing wrong. As per both [WSDL's `TimeServiceSoap` documentation](http://www.altova.com/library/wsdl/wsdl_documentation.html#Link03CB0A80) and Java naming conventions, method names are in camel case beginning with a lowercase letter.

Comment: Thank you that worked.  When I ran wsimport I could only find references to a G not g.

Answer (score 1):

What does your `TimeServiceSoap` look like?

Perhaps you meant to use `getTimeZoneTime()` (starting with a lower case letter)?